# How can I order a query by a related field?

Tags: yii

Using Yii 1.1.15 assume I have a model:

```
State(id,name) ----- 1<>N ----- City(id,state_id,name)
#the only relevant field in each is `name`, having City the
#corresponding FK field to State.
```

And want to query *cities sorted (asc) by State Name, and then (asc) by City name*.

```
City::model()->with('state')->findAll(array('order' => 'name ASC'));
```

How do I alter the sort criteria to consider the state name?

(footnote: in other frameworks like Python/Django I'd do `City.objects.select_related('state').order_by('state__name', 'name')` - i.e. many frameworks have support for a nested ordering - does Yii have as well?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe this

```
City::model()->with(array('with'=>array(
                        'state'=>array(
                            'alias'=>'v',
                            'order'=>'t.name  ASC',
                        )
                    ))->findAll();
```

Comment: It worked like this: `City::model()->with('state'=>array('alias'=>'s', 'order'=>'s.name ASC'))->findAll()`